# R significantly slows down with compiler (JIT)

Tags: r, performance, compiler-construction, jit

I have interesting results when I use "compiler" to speed up my code. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106736/possible-shortcomings-for-using-jit-with-r/10130250#10130250) but I feel my question isn't answered there.

I have a function that consists of several different functions and for loops within. Essentially it is a regularised logistic regression with glmnet but it's run several times. Let's call this function myFunction.

For each method I tried, I will jot down the average times of several runs:

```
temp <- NULL
for (i in 1:10) temp <- c(temp,system.time(myFunction())["elapsed"])
mean(temp)
```

[1] 19.189

```
enableJIT(1)
temp <- NULL
for (i in 1:10) temp <- c(temp,system.time(myFunction())["elapsed"])
mean(temp)
```

[1] 38.668

```
enableJIT(0)
temp <- NULL
for (i in 1:10) temp <- c(temp,system.time(myFunction())["elapsed"])
mean(temp)
```

[1] 17.790

Please note that each results I write here are the average of 10 runs and within each, the times are close to each other.

Q1) Any ideas why it increases so much with enableJIT(1)? I expected it to increase in the first run but even in the next runs, the time is within 37-40 seconds range.

Q2) Any ideas why it decreases further less than the original version when enableJIT(0) is done afterwards?

Thanks in advance for the guidance.

Comment: I have experienced this as well sometimes. From what I have read in several websites (many of them here at SO), the very first instance of a function call will be slower with byte code compiling. Hence, if you have only few iterations, it might not be worthwhile doing it. If you have many, you might catch up.

Comment: That's what I thought as well. But there is not much difference from the first run till the last. Here are the results from another function (call it myFunction2) after calling enableJIT(1):

16.736  17.111  17.507  17.890  17.484  15.202  15.285  16.002  15.775 15.940

So the last run is still as slow as the first one..

Comment: Does the same happen when you don't use enableJIT, but when you compile the function "manually"? I.e. `library(compiler); myfun <- cmpfun(myfun)`?

Comment: There are many functions within that function as well, but when I compiled this function and a couple of others within it, it slightly decreased (10%) the time. I wanted to try enableJIT mostly because I thought it'd compile all these functions so I'd gain more than 10%.

Comment: Interesting. Please post if you find a solution. On a side note, (even though unrelated to your question) you apparently want to speed up the process, and since you explicitly mentioned for-loops, maybe you want to look into the possibility to parallelize your code. This is often easier than people think, and for computation intensive processes, it is worthwhile doing. See `?parallel`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm actually utilising parallel right now. I guess now I'm just trying to squeeze any additional speed :) I have read Rcpp is pretty effective but it requires a lot of C++ coding and I think it'd be too difficult to make it work with my long code.