# when is R's `ByteCompile` counter-productive?

Tags: r

The R docs describe the `ByteCompile` field in the "[DESCRIPTION file](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#The-DESCRIPTION-file)" section as:

> The ‘ByteCompile’ logical field controls if the package code is to be byte-compiled on installation: the default is currently not to, so this may be useful for a package known to benefit particularly from byte-compilation (which can take quite a long time and increases the installed size of the package)

I infer the only detrimental side-effects to byte-compiling are (a) time-to-install and (b) installation size. I haven't found a package that takes too long during installation/byte-compiling, and the general consensus is that GBs are cheap (for storage).

**Q**: When should I choose to *not* byte-compile packages I write? (Does anybody have anecdotal or empirical limits beyond which they choose against it?)

**Edit**: As noted in the comments of an [older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343243/r-2-14-byte-compile-why-not), the rationale that debugging is not possible with byte-compiled code has been debunked. Other related questions on SO have discussed *how* to do it (either manually with `R CMD INSTALL --byte-compile ...` or with `install.packages(..., type="source", INSTALL_opts="--byte-compile")`), but have not discussed the ramifications of or arguments against doing so.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8343243/602276, but the answer over there seems incomplete. Perhaps time for a new answer?

Comment: @Andrie That question/answer is certainly in need for an update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have yet to find a downside for byte-compiling, other than the ones you mention: slightly increased file size and installation time.

In the past, compiling certain code could cause [slow-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106736/possible-shortcomings-for-using-jit-with-r) but in recent versions of R (version >3.3.0), this doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: I've found byte compiling during development to be problematic: debugging is more spartan when byte compiled; though my dev cycle typically involves frequenting `source`ing vice build/install, the latter is still necessary pre-deployment. I wasn't aware of that previous JIT problem, good to know it is history. Thanks for your thoughts on a slightly "stale" question! :-)

Comment: Could you provide a few more details on "debugging". I've been using byte-compiling for awhile and not had any issues.

Comment: Using emacs/ESS (I do not use RStudio), when debugging a `source`d function, ESS does next-line highlighting in the source file, following step-by-step. With a byte-compiled function, the source file is not known so this is not possible. Perhaps it's a limitation of emacs/ESS and not of R?

Comment: ... though without the source file reference (`srcref` and http://stackoverflow.com/a/32749240/3358272), I don't know how any IDEs would be able to follow and provide in-source context.

Comment: Support for source references in byte-compiled code has just been added to the R development version last week. You can, even in older versions of R, debug byte-compiled functions using `debug` (set `debug` on the function and then run it) - effectively this works by interpreting the AST of the function (ignoring its byte-code).

Comment: You are very unlikely to get a slowdown with the byte-code compiler. If you use JIT on very short-running code, there could be slowdown because of the compilation time. Then you can get slowdown in case of very strange programming patterns (like frequent replacement of closure-environment that causes the need to re-compile, so again the overhead is compile time). This happens very rarely.